# How to make image auto fit to the max size of container?

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have a container which would have several images. I want

1.) when there is only one image, the image take whole space:

```
 ------------------Container----------------
 | --------------------------------------- |
 | |                                     | |
 | |                                     | |
 | |           Image                     | |
 | |                                     | |
 | |                                     | |
 | --------------------------------------- |
 -------------------------------------------
```

B) when there are two images

```
 ------------------Container----------------
 | -------------------- ------------------ |
 | |                  | |                | |
 | |                  | |                | |
 | |     Image 1      | |     Image 2    | |
 | |                  | |                | |
 | |                  | |                | |
 | -------------------- ------------------ |
 -------------------------------------------
```

C) If there are 3 or 4 images, remain in same row

```
 ------------------Container----------------
 | --------- --------- --------- --------- |
 | |       | |       | |       | |       | |
 | |       | |       | |       | |       | |
 | |       | |       | |       | |       | |
 | |       | |       | |       | |       | |
 | |       | |       | |       | |       | |
 | --------- --------- --------- --------- |
 -------------------------------------------
```

D) When there are 5 images, there will be two rows, 4 images in first row and 1 image in second row.

```
 ------------------Container----------------
 | --------- --------- --------- --------- |
 | |       | |       | |       | |       | |
 | |       | |       | |       | |       | |
 | |       | |       | |       | |       | |
 | |       | |       | |       | |       | |
 | |       | |       | |       | |       | |
 | --------- --------- --------- --------- |
 | ---------                               |
 | |       |                               |
 | |       |                               |
 | |       |                               |
 | |       |                               |
 | |       |                               |
 | --------- --------- --------- --------- |
 -------------------------------------------
```

Is it possible do it in `css` without `js`?

And is there any libs can do that?

Comment: have you tried width = inherit and height inherit too ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This can be achieved using `flexbox`:

- Add `display: flex;` and `flex-wrap: wrap;` to the element containing the `img`s. `display: flex;` tells the elements children to use the flexbox model. `flex-wrap: wrap;` allows for the elements to wrap onto new lines.
- Add `flex: 1 0 25%;` (shorthand for `flex-grow`, `flex-shrink` and `flex-basis`) to the images `img`s. `flex-grow` tells the element that it can grow if need be, `flex-shrink` that it can shrink. `flex-basis` is the default width of the element, `25%` in this case as you want 4 `img`s in a row.

```css
.container {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    height: 200px;
    width: 100%;
}
.container img {
    flex: 1 0 25%;
}
```

```html
<strong>1</strong>
<div class="container">
    <img alt="" src="http://placehold.it/300x300" />
</div>
<strong>2</strong>
<div class="container">
    <img alt="" src="http://placehold.it/300x300" />
    <img alt="" src="http://placehold.it/300x300" />
</div>
<strong>3</strong>
<div class="container">
    <img alt="" src="http://placehold.it/300x300" />
    <img alt="" src="http://placehold.it/300x300" />
    <img alt="" src="http://placehold.it/300x300" />
</div>
<strong>4</strong>
<div class="container">
    <img alt="" src="http://placehold.it/300x300" />
    <img alt="" src="http://placehold.it/300x300" />
    <img alt="" src="http://placehold.it/300x300" />
    <img alt="" src="http://placehold.it/300x300" />
</div>
<strong>5</strong>
<div class="container">
    <img alt="" src="http://placehold.it/300x300" />
    <img alt="" src="http://placehold.it/300x300" />
    <img alt="" src="http://placehold.it/300x300" />
    <img alt="" src="http://placehold.it/300x300" />
    <img alt="" src="http://placehold.it/300x300" />
</div>
```

Comment: `Flexbox` is still a bit buggy and needs some workarounds to make it crossbrowser compatible: [https://github.com/philipwalton/flexbugs](https://github.com/philipwalton/flexbugs)

Comment: @Michel Useful link, I'll keep that bookmarked! Don't think I've run into any of the issues yet but it would appear that certain combinations of CSS can cause problems. Overall support for `flexbox` is pretty good http://caniuse.com/#feat=flexbox although fallbacks will be required for older versions of IE.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it's possible to do with just css. You don't need a library either. The CSS Flexbox Layout technique would be ideal for this.

***From CSS Tricks***

*The Flexbox Layout (Flexible Box) module (currently a W3C Last Call Working Draft) aims at providing a more efficient way to lay out, align and distribute space among items in a container, even when their size is unknown and/or dynamic (thus the word "flex").*

See https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/ for more.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add javaScript

HTML

```
<div class "container">
    <img class="showBigImage" src="http://www.online-image-editor.com//styles/2014/images/example_image.png" />
    <img class="showBigImage" src="http://www.online-image-editor.com//styles/2014/images/example_image.png" />
    <img class="showBigImage" src="http://www.online-image-editor.com//styles/2014/images/example_image.png" />
```

CSS

```
.container {
    width:100%
}
.showBigImage {
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
    display:block;
    float:left
}
```

JavaScript

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var totalImg = $(".showBigImage").length;
    if(totalImg > 4){
       $(".showBigImage").css("width", "25%")
    }else{
         $(".showBigImage").css("width", (100 / totalImg) + "%")
    }

});
```

Comment: @Sato You need to add some more CSS for your design and do some more calculation for add some padding.

Answer (score 0):

So I will advise first you create a special class for those images. dynamicImages maybe?

```
.dynamicImages{
     //apply style you want here
}
```

Then once you have this, you can also create a container div:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row dynamicImages"></div>
</di>
```

Now If you are getting your images from a database you can use a while loop to loop through the images. If you creating the images yourself without taking them from the database, you might want to create the image tag with the dynamicImages class in them

```
<div class="row dynamicImages">
    <img class="img-responsive" src="#">
    <img class="img-responsive" src="#">
    <img class="img-responsive" src="#">
<div>
```

Now using js you check for the number of images you have:

```
if($("#dynamicImages > img").length == 1){

       //col-sm-12 allows you to occupy the whole row
       $("#dynamicImages > img").addClass("col-sm-12");

 }else if($("#dynamicImages > img").length == 2){
       //the col-sm-6 allows two per row. 
       $("#dynamicImages > img").addClass("col-sm-6");
 }else if($("#dynamicImages > img").length >= 3 ){
       //the col-sm-3 allows 4 per row in bootstrap 
       $("#dynamicImages > img").addClass("col-sm-3");
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Without using any bit of `Javascript` and avoid worrying about `cross-browser compatibility` 
What you have to do is based on the relationship between `:nth-child` and `:nth-last-child`. As you can see in the below code, the number of total rules is O(N) and the number of selectors in every rule is also O(N).

However, what you really want, is to just target the first element. The others can be targeted with just a sibling selector.

```
/* one item */
img:first-child:nth-last-child(1) {
    width: 100%;
}

/* two items */
img:first-child:nth-last-child(2),
img:first-child:nth-last-child(2) ~ img {
    width: 50%;
}

/* three items */
img:first-child:nth-last-child(3),
img:first-child:nth-last-child(3) ~ img {
    width: 33.3333%;
}

/* four items */
img:first-child:nth-last-child(4),
img:first-child:nth-last-child(4) ~ img {
    width: 25%;
}

/* This one resets the sizes when you get over 4 images */
.content > img {
  width: 25%;
}
```

Go ahead and play with the number of images in this [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/3hFcNn5MRsYm2YWDEm6z?p=preview) I've made for you